# Hibernate : org.hibernate.WrongClassException when I try to remove an object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using inheritance to describe my model on JPA with hibernate, I have this classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Evento implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "numero")
    private String numeroEvento;
```

And this child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento_sesion")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idevento", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class EventoSesion extends Evento implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "objeto")
    private String objeto;
...
```

The problem is when I try to do a "eventoFacade.remove(e)" (e is an instance of an existent object in DB) I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: null was not of the specified subclass: entidades.Evento (class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy)
```

Somebody can help me or give me a clue?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give us more information? I have just defined the two classes as shown above and I could not reproduce the error you describe. I have added a new instance of type `EventoSession` and then loaded it as an object of type `Evento` and could remove it without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I try to give an answer, but the answer will be speculative; the problem is in the code which performs the `remove` on the entity manager, i.e. in `eventoFacade.remove(e)`.

However, assume that you have created and stored an Entity of type `EventoSession` in the database, and then you try to invoke `em.remove` with an instance of the base type, then you get the exception which you mentioned.

Let us assume, that the entity of type `EventoSession` has the primary key 1, and now we try to remove this entity.

```
Evento es = new Evento();
es.setNumeroEvento("...");
es.setId(1);

es = em.merge(es); // detached objects cannot be removed, therefore we merge es
em.remove(es);
```

The call to `em.merge` will then end in a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException`, caused by:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: 
    Object [id=null] was not of the specified subclass [entidades.Evento]: 
    class of the given object did not match class of persistent copy
```

and I assume that this could be the problem.

To fix it, simply load the instance to be removed over the entity manager:

```
em.remove(em.find(Evento.class, 1));
```